# veshape of type in pushpin in bing map

Tags: bing

I am making a website in which veshape is there of type pushpin and a gridview aside bing map.
Now pushpin is draggable and can drag oustside of map. I want drap and drop feature of pushpin on gridview .When pushpin is drop on the gridview I want a piece of information of pushpin and grid current row on which pushpin is drop.
How i accomplish this?